# Can't download javax.comm

Tags: java, api, download, serial-port, javax.comm

I'm making a Java ECG Software which needs to be able to communicate with an ECG through serial communication. However, the java API javax.comm is nowhere to be found. I have searched [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html) but there's no download link whatsoever.

Does anyone know where I can find the API?

I don't care if it's for Linux(Ubuntu) or OS X. I found an old API for windows (which is no longer supported) but it did not work on my 64 bit windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it with this search : https://www.google.com/search?q=%22comm.jar%22+Index+of
However it's probably the same old version you already have.

Comment: THIS is a viable answer! You will get all sorts of hits, some from the old version but some from the new. Snagged a v 2.0.3 from one of the links it provided.

It's absolutely shameful that Oracle makes us resort to such strategies.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked with it (for a credit card scanner/signature pad). I remember using rxtx, though I don't remember if I also used an oracle download. I believe the rxtx implementation was sufficient. Just be aware that mixing 32 bit linux libs with 64 bit linux jvms is a no-no. At a minimum, you'd need a recompile or the linking/loading process of the lib will fail.

http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page